# Nanoflann findNeighbors raise segfault

Tags: c++, class, kdtree, flann

So I have the following class KdTree:

```cpp
#include <nanoflann.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct PointCloud
{
    struct Point
    {
        double  x,y,z;
    };

    std::vector<Point>  pts;

    inline size_t kdtree_get_point_count() const { return pts.size(); }

    inline double kdtree_get_pt(const size_t idx, const size_t dim) const
    {
        if (dim == 0) return pts[idx].x;
        else if (dim == 1) return pts[idx].y;
        else if (dim == 2) return pts[idx].z;
    }

    template <class BBOX>
    bool kdtree_get_bbox(BBOX& /* bb */) const { return false; }

};

void generatePointCloud(PointCloud &point, const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& given)
{
    point.pts.resize(given.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < given.size(); ++i) {
    point.pts[i].x = given[i][0];
    point.pts[i].y = given[i][1];
    point.pts[i].z = given[i][2];
}
}

using namespace nanoflann;
using Points = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

class KdTree {
public:
    KdTree(const Points& points) {
        PointCloud cloud;
        generatePointCloud(cloud, points); // just puts points into cloud format
        index = std::make_shared<my_kd_tree>(3 /*dim*/, cloud, KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptorParams(10 /* max leaf */) );
        index->buildIndex();
    }

    size_t GetNearest(const std::vector<double>& pt) const {
        double query_pt[3] = { pt[0], pt[1], pt[2] };
        const size_t num_results = 1;
        size_t ret_index;
        double out_dist_sqr;
        nanoflann::KNNResultSet<double > resultSet(num_results);
        resultSet.init(&ret_index, &out_dist_sqr );
        index->findNeighbors(resultSet, &query_pt[0], nanoflann::SearchParams(10));
        std::cout << "knnSearch(nn="<<num_results<<"): \n";
        std::cout << "ret_index=" << ret_index << " out_dist_sqr=" << out_dist_sqr << endl;
        return ret_index;
    }

    typedef KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptor<
            L2_Simple_Adaptor<double , PointCloud > ,
            PointCloud,
            3 /* dim */
    > my_kd_tree;
    std::shared_ptr<my_kd_tree> index = nullptr;
};
```

The problem is that the following code raises segfault:

```cpp
int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
    Points points{{1, 5, 8}, {3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 0}};
    KdTree tree(points);
    tree.GetNearest({1, 1, 1});
    return 0;
}
```

But if I put `GetNearest` code in constructor (so that I construct index and find `pt`'s neighbor in constructor itself), or just write constructor and `GetNearest` code in main, then everything works just fine.

I am new to nanoflann, can't figure what's wrong. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik fails on `findNeighbors` with segfault on the first line of `kdtree_get_pt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to dig into the source [nanoflann.hpp](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann/blob/master/include/nanoflann.hpp) to find that the second parameter to the constructor for `KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptor` (`cloud` in your `KdTree` constructor) is passed by reference and *stored* as a reference.  This means that the cloud data you pass to nanoflann needs to stay around until you delete the `KDTreeSingleIndexAdaptor` object.

Because you declare `PointCloud cloud` as a local variable within your `KdTree` constructor, it will be destroyed when the constructor ends leaving the kdtree pointed to by `index` with an dangling internal reference.

One solution is to make `cloud` a member of `KdTree`.